# Removing punctuation and creating a set from words from user input

Tags: python

I was wondering how I might go about removing punctuation from user input and creating a set from the words in the input. So far I have this.

```
input_set = set(self.entry.get().lower().split(' '))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

Python2:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> s = 'sfda%$$sdafd dasf564%^%^, hgghg%#56'
>>> set(s.translate(None, punctuation).split())
set(['hgghg56', 'dasf564', 'sfdasdafd'])
```

Python3:

```
from string import punctuation
s = 'sfda%$$sdafd dasf564%^%^, hgghg%#56'
tab = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punctuation))
print (set(s.translate(tab).split()))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an excellent place to use regular expressions:

```
import re
re.split(r'\W+',str)
```

depending on what you consider punctuation you may want to change '\W' to a different character class or character group.

Comment: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.'

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove punctuation: see [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)
2. Create a set of words: `set(sentence.split(' '))`